# Prototype: Need a javascript autosuggest tool

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, prototypejs

HI guys I'm building a web mail client interface and would like an autosuggest script that could be used in filling out the recipient addresses. I've checked a few scripts but they limit by either allowing to choose only one element, or you can enter only elements from the drop down list - I just need one which not only allows you to add multiple selections but you can also type in and add values that are not included within the selection as well.

Oh it has to be prototype based. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Script.aculo.us](http://script.aculo.us/) has [autocomplete](http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/scriptaculous-autocomplete.html) and is based on Prototype.

Answer (score 0):

I've also like [this one](http://www.beauscott.com/examples/autocomplete/doc/examples.html) with and without scriptaculous.